copy and paste the url causes a no registered service for ApiClient using fast-endpoints
I have a Blazor .Net 8 WASM web app global (InteractiveWebAssembly)
I'm using FastEndpoints and the  FastEndpoints.ClientGen
The application runs fine, but if I copy and paste the url to another tab I get errors like this.
InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'Api' on type 'MyHebrewBible.Client.Features.BookChapter.Verses.Sections'.
There is no registered service of type 'MyHebrewBible.Client.ApiClient'.
The server app is setup like this in the Program.cs file
In Program.cs on the server app, FastEndpoints is setup like this
    app.UseAuthentication()
         .UseAuthorization()
         .UseFastEndpoints(
                 c =>
                 {
                     c.Endpoints.ShortNames = true;
                     c.Endpoints.RoutePrefix = "api";
                     c.Serializer.Options.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                 });


    await app.GenerateClientsAndExitAsync(
            documentName: "MyHebrewBibleApi",
            destinationPath: "../MyHebrewBible.Client/HttpClient",
            csSettings: c =>
            {
                c.ClassName = "ApiClient";
                c.CSharpGeneratorSettings.Namespace = "MyHebrewBible.Client";
                c.CSharpGeneratorSettings.JsonLibrary = CSharpJsonLibrary.SystemTextJson;
            },
            tsSettings: null);


This generates an HttpClient on the Client app and when I need it in my razor components, do this @inject ApiClient Api
In Program.cs on the client app, the code generated ApiClient is setup like this
builder.Services.AddSingleton(
        new ApiClient(
                builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress,
                new() { BaseAddress = new(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) }));

I have a lot of experience with Blazor Server but very little with WASM and API's
I'm sure there's a simple solution or well known technique that I'm missing.

The solution was to create a LoadingProgress component that got wrapped around calls to the ApiClient.
For more details follow the link below
https://github.com/JohnMarsing/Mhb-FastEndpoints-Hosted-Blazor-Wasm/wiki/No-Registered-Service-Exception-%7C-LoadingProgress
